# SPARQL Filtering a COUNT

Tags: rdf, sparql

I want to filter a count result. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?total)
WHERE {
    ?s sf:RatioSWO ?o .
 }
GROUP BY ?total
```

This only gives me the total rows of the predicate. I've tried filtering by placing a "< 0.5" after the COUNT(*) but this just gives me a result of "false" which I have no idea what that means. I've also tried HAVING and FILTER but both give me no results.

Comment: What exactly do you want the query to return? `COUNT(*) < 0.5` simply means that you check if the number of results matching the triple `?s sf:RatioSWO ?o` is less then `0.5`, which doesn't really make sense. It gives you `true` if there are any results and `false` otherwise. You have to make it clearer.

Comment: What's more, the `GROUP BY` statement doesn't seem logical in this case. In this query, you're using a variable that is supposed to be its result. It's not syntactically correct. It will never get assigned. How does it return anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but how about this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?total)
WHERE {
    ?s sf:RatioSWO ?o .
    FILTER (?o < 0.5)
}
```

This counts the number of `sf:RatioSWO` triples where the value is greater than 0.5.

Comment: This is a super old post but I am learning sparql now and I want to use FILTER ( ?val < 10). But if I want to store this 10 in anpther variable, say 'counter', is that still possible ? Like, FILTER ( ?val <  counter )

Comment: @savi Comparing two variables is possible: BIND (10 AS ?max). FILTER (?val < ?max). If you have something more complex in mind, it's perhaps best to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @cygri for the response. I have asked my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616643/is-there-a-way-to-parameterize-a-sparql-filter-condition  With BIND again, 10 is getting hard-coded. I need to take the value of count as a user-input.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to return the ?total-s where ?total is < 0.5 you can do:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?total)
WHERE {
    ?s sf:RatioSWO ?o .
}
GROUP BY ?s
HAVING (?total < 0.5)
```

From the question it's not clear what you mean.