# is there a way to parameterize a sparql filter condition?

Tags: python, filter, sparql, rdf

I am trying to find out what is the best way to parameterize a filter condition with a float value taken as input.

```
count=25.67
FILTER(?price < count)
```

instead of:

```
FILTER ( ?price < 25.67 )
```

The value of "count" will be taken as input.

I would like to know the syntax for including the object count in the FILTER command.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: and standard python inline strings do not work? some APIs do also support parameterized queries and some triple stores do even support providing variable bindings via HTTP param. But for me the obvious why is to just use Python f-string or something, or is this not what you were asking for?

Comment: Strings inline do work. But I want to automate it to accept the input that a user gives. Say, I store that in a float variable, my question is, what is the grammar in rdf to use the object in FILTER command of sparql ?

Comment: not sure what you're asking, for me user enters the value and then you create the query string and just execute it. And you create the string by either replacing some placeholder or just do inline string creation. `s = f"select ... where { ... FILTER(?price < {count})}"`  - why is this not working? It's the most obvious and in my opinion simple way. Or not? Indeed, f-string is Python 3.6, but you can also use `str.format` in pevious Python versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of `setQuery` use with a parameter added via `.format():

```py
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON


def query_dbpedia(my_uri)
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
    q = """
        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

        SELECT ?label
        WHERE {{
            {} rdfs:label ?label .
        }}
    """.format(my_uri)
    sparql.setQuery(q)
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    results = sparql.query().convert()

    results_to_return = []
    for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
        results_to_return.append(result["label"]["value"])

    return results_to_return

print(query_dbpedia("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asturias"))
```

(adapted from SPARQLWrapper documentation at https://sparqlwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html)

Comment: Thanks @nicholas-car for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic SPARQL syntax to do this: like SQL, you have to make a SPARQL query out of a string, at least in Python. Therefore, any user input you want has to make the string that you then send as the query. Say you wanted to get all prices greater than `price_to_be_less_than`, you would do this in [RDFlib](https://rdflib.dev) Python:

```py
def get_prices(g, price_to_be_less_than):
    q = """
        SELECT ?item 
        WHERE {{
            ?item ex:hasPrice ?price .

            FILTER (?price < {})
        }}
        """.format(price_to_be_less_than)

       items = []
       for r in g.query(q):
           items.append(r["item"])

       return items
```

I use `.format()`, not f-strings (personal taste), so I then have to use double braces, "{{", in the query

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I am using the .setQuery() of sparqlwrapper to send in the query. I understand that I should use { }  in the FILTER command and then use .format(count). How would i include .format with sparql.setQuery(" --query--")  ?

Comment: @savi this is exactly what I already told you, the query is just a plain string - nothing more nothing less. I also don't understand your follow up question here, q is a string, you can pass this to the method  `sparql.setQuery(q)`, what's wrong with using an extra variable for the query string? And if you really don't want this, just copy and paste the right side of the query string assignment `q = ` into the method.